# Issue with method name, Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, method-names

I am working on a booking application for learning purposes,  a problem with a method name in the repository interface

```
  Optional<Room> findByIdAndStatus(int id, status status);
```

and I am always getting this error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-04-12T01:52:06.873+02:00 ERROR 11064 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'roomController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'roomService': Error creating bean with name 'roomService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'roomRepository': Error creating bean with name 'roomRepository' defined in com.beClean.soba1.soba1.Repository.RoomRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Optional com.beClean.soba1.soba1.Repository.RoomRepository.findByIdAndStatus(int,com.beClean.soba1.soba1.Entities.Room$status); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.beClean.soba1.soba1.Repository.RoomRepository.findByIdAndStatus(int,com.beClean.soba1.soba1.Entities.Room$status); No property 'id' found for type 'Room' Did you mean ''tip''
```

This is my entity file:

```
package com.beClean.soba1.soba1.Entities;

import java.util.List;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EnumType;
import jakarta.persistence.Enumerated;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Version;

@Entity(name="soba")
public class Room {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int soba_id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="hotel_id")
    Hotel hotel;
    private String tip;
    private double cena;
    private String opis;
    public enum status {SLOBODNO, ZAUZETO}; 
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private status status;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "room")
    private List<Booking>listaRezervacija;
    
    //@Version
    //int versionNumber = 0;

    public Room(int soba_id, Hotel hotel, String tip, double cena, String opis,status status) {
        this.soba_id = soba_id;
        this.hotel = hotel;
        this.tip = tip;
        this.cena = cena;
        this.opis = opis;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Room() {
    }

    public int getSoba_id() {
        return soba_id;
    }

    public void setSoba_id(int soba_id) {
        this.soba_id = soba_id;
    }

    public Hotel getHotel() {
        return hotel;
    }

    public void setHotel(Hotel hotel) {
        this.hotel = hotel;
    }

    public String getTip() {
        return tip;
    }

    public void setTip(String tip) {
        this.tip = tip;
    }

    public double getCena() {
        return cena;
    }

    public void setCena(double cena) {
        this.cena = cena;
    }

    public String getOpis() {
        return opis;
    }

    public void setOpis(String opis) {
        this.opis = opis;
    }

    public status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    
}
```

This is my repository file:

```
package com.beClean.soba1.soba1.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.beClean.soba1.soba1.Entities.Room;
import com.beClean.soba1.soba1.Entities.Room.status;

import ch.qos.logback.core.status.Status;


public interface RoomRepository extends CrudRepository<Room, Integer>{
    
    @Query("select s from soba s where s.tip = 'trokrevetna'")
    List<Room>findAllTrokrevetna();
    
    @Query("select s from soba s where s.tip = 'dvokrevetna'")
    List<Room>findAllDvokrevetna();
    
    //nadji sobe koje su jeftinije od date cene
    List<Room>findByCenaLessThan(double cena);
    
    //sortiraj od najjeftinije do najskuplje
    List<Room> findByOrderByCenaAsc();
    
    //sortiraj od najskuplje do najjeftinije
    List<Room>findByOrderByCenaDesc();
    
    
      Optional<Room> findById(int id);
    

     List<Room> findByStatus(Status status);

    Optional<Room> findByIdAndStatus(int id, status status);
}
```

this is my service file:

```
package com.beClean.soba1.soba1.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;

import com.beClean.soba1.soba1.Entities.Room;
import com.beClean.soba1.soba1.Entities.Room.status;
import com.beClean.soba1.soba1.Repository.RoomRepository;

import ch.qos.logback.core.status.Status;

@Service
public class RoomService {
    @Autowired
    RoomRepository roomRepository;
    
    public List<Room>getAllRooms(){
        return (List<Room>) roomRepository.findAll();
    
    }
    public Room getRoomById(int id) {
        return getIfPresentOrThrow(roomRepository.findById(id));
    }
    public List<Room> getAllTrokrevetna(){
    return roomRepository.findAllTrokrevetna();
}

     public List<Room>getAllDvokrevetna(){
    return roomRepository.findAllDvokrevetna();
}
     public List<Room> getRoomByCenaLessThan(@PathVariable double cena){
         return roomRepository.findByCenaLessThan(cena);
     }
     
     public List<Room>getByOrderByCenaAsc(){
         return roomRepository.findByOrderByCenaAsc();
     }
     
     public List<Room> getByOrderByCenaDesc() {
         return roomRepository.findByOrderByCenaDesc();
        
    }
     public List<Room>getRoomByStatus(Status status){
     return roomRepository.findByStatus(status);
 }
     private Room getIfPresentOrThrow(Optional<Room> optionalRoom) {
            if (!optionalRoom.isPresent()) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            return optionalRoom.get();
          }
   public Room getRoomByIdAndStatus(int id, status status) {
            return getIfPresentOrThrow(roomRepository.findByIdAndStatus(id, status));
          }
}
```

and the controller file:

```
package com.beClean.soba1.soba1.Controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ReturnMetadata;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.beClean.soba1.soba1.Entities.Room;
import com.beClean.soba1.soba1.Entities.Room.status;
import com.beClean.soba1.soba1.Service.RoomService;

import ch.qos.logback.core.status.Status;

@RestController
public class RoomController {
    @Autowired
    RoomService roomService;
    
    @GetMapping("/room")
    public List<Room>getAllRooms(){
        return(List<Room>) roomService.getAllRooms();
    }

    @GetMapping("/room/{id}")
    public Room getRoomById(@PathVariable int id) {
        return roomService.getRoomById(id);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/trokrevetna")
    public List<Room>getAllTrokrevetna(){
        return roomService.getAllTrokrevetna();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/dvokrevetna")
    public List<Room>findAlldvokrevetna(){
        return roomService.getAllDvokrevetna();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/jeftinije/{cena}")
    public List<Room>getRoomByCenaLessThan(@PathVariable double cena){
        return roomService.getRoomByCenaLessThan(cena);
    }
    @GetMapping("/najjeftinije")
    public List<Room>getByOrderByCenaAsc(){
        return roomService.getByOrderByCenaAsc();
    }
    @GetMapping("/najskuplje")
    public List<Room>GetByOrderByCenaDesc(){
        return roomService.getByOrderByCenaDesc();
    }
    @GetMapping("/{status}")
    public List<Room>getRoomByStatus(Status status){
        return roomService.getRoomByStatus(status);
    }
}
```

I'm a newbie, I've tried almost everything I could think of with naming, without success.. :( Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just a guess: Try changing `int` to `Integer` for all uses of `id`.

Comment: _"No property 'id' found for type 'Room'"_ -- I don't see an `id` property anywhere.

Comment: When you get an error message you need to read the entire message.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is here

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int soba_id;
```

Spring JPA querying is accomplished in two steps: first, use "@Query," followed by your custom query. second is [Derived Query Methods](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-derived-queries) which is your case, and it works by name, so when your method

```
  Optional<Room> findByIdAndStatus(int id, status status);
```

has `findByIdAndStatus` Spring will look at the model of the repository, which in your case is Room.java and check for fields called `id` and `status`, so if you rename your `soba_id` to

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
```

it should be fine, additionally if you want to keep the name soba_id on db level you can apply `@Column(name = "soba_id")` and everything is ok